# Question regarding isolation and level shifting

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, isolation, logic-level

What are the requirements that make one choose between physical isolation and simple logic level shifter circuits when you have two devices communicating with each other.

For example, a circuit containing an IC that is powered with 5V and outputs 5V signals that is fed into an MCU that is 3.3V powered with input pins rated for 3.3V.

Am I correct in saying if they are both powered with the same supply, no isolation is required. However if they were supplied with two different power supplies, isolation is required?

Comment: It is very common for two different supplies to share a common ground. In these cases only level shifting is required (usually).

Comment: If the two devices are known or suspected to be, or possibly at some point could be, at different potentials, if ground loops may be an issue, or where the distance between the two devices is large, galvanic isolation should be considered.

Comment: So for example isolation is required between a device powered by a computer USB and another device powered by a bench top power supply?